# Kundalini - the serpent in the bowl

Tags: kundalini

Kundalini is commonly said to be a coiled serpent - snake of immense power resting - asleep - torpid in the bowl at the base of the spine. Is she really there and Why is She coiled, or should I ask is she really coiled and why is she resting, or is this all  a diluted myth that has flowed down the river of time from her true origin where realized knowledge was the reality?

Comment: I suggest that you read the 250 page introduction in the book, The Serpent Power' by Arthur AValon (Sir John Woodroffe).

Comment: A difficult read is that. To see know and realize would be better would it not Pradip.

Comment: Alongside with many scriptures many other saints like Nandikeshara, Upamanyu, Tirumular, Matsyendranath, Gorakhnath, Vasugupta, Abhinavagupta, Sambhunatha, Ramakrishna, Vivekananda, etc... realized Kundalini and she is there....

Comment: The kundalini is described - and the key word is described - as being coiled as it is not awake in most humans. Real snakes when they sleep oftentimes coil up to keep heat within as they are cold blooded. Metaphors work one way....

Answer (score 3):

## Is she really there and Why is She coiled, or should I ask is she really coiled and why is she resting ?

**No , Kundalini as energy is not a Myth.** The energy is there. This fact is advocated by multiple Hinduism  scriptures which are describing Kundalini Shakti and how to awaken her in order to get the liberation or Moksha.

The Kundalini shakti resides   in our  subtle body and remains there always, but part of her divine energy is in our physical body which is also called as  the gross body and manifested as Prana, Apana, Vyana, Samana and Udana.

---

[**Shandilya Upanishad**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shandilya-upanishad-of-atharvaveda/d/doc217052.html) of Atharvaveda - Chapter I -Tells us that this Kundalini shakti is one of the forms of eight Prakritis.

> As a spider flies to and fro within a web of fine threads, so prāṇa
>   moves about here. In this body, the jīva rides upon prāṇa. **Lying in
>   the middle of the navel and above it, is the seat of kundalinī. The
>   kundalinī śakti is of the form of eight prakṛtis (matter) and coils
>   itself eight ways or (times).** The movement of vāyus (vital airs)
>   checks duly the food and drink all round by the side of skandha.[2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/hatha-yoga-pradipika-english/d/doc7976.html) It
>   closes by its head (the opening of) the brahmarandhra, and during the
>   time of (the practice of) yoga is awakened by the fire (in the apāna);
>   then it shines with great brilliancy in the ākāś of the heart in the
>   shape of wisdom

---

The [**Yoga-Kundalini Upanishad**](http://www.purna-yoga.ru/en/library/text/ancent/Yoga-Kundalini_Upanishad.pdf) - Chapter 1 - Verse 82 - also confirms the above.

> शक्ति: कुण्डलिनि नाम बिसतन्तुनिभा शुभा |
>  मूलकन्दं फणाग्रेण
>   दृष्ट्वा कमलकन्दवत् || 1.82||
>
> The Sakti named Kundalini, which is like a thread in the lotus and is
>   resplendent, is biting with the upper end of its hood (namely, mouth)
>   at the root of the lotus the Mulakanda

---

Kundalini Power is said to be a Goddess a Shakti as creator and sustainer  of the universe . [**The  Hatha Yoga Pradipika**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/hatha-yoga-pradipika-english/d/doc7976.html) is the authoritative book which talks about Kundalini . It is said in the book that  " The Kundalini is sleeping, closing the door of the Sushumna. She sleeps above the Kanda or where the Nadis unite. She gives liberation to the Yogi and bondage to fools. He who knows her knows Yoga."

> तस्मात्सर्व-परयत्नेन परबोधयितुमीश्वरीम |
>  बरह्म-दवार-मुखे सुप्तां
>   मुद्राभ्यासं समाछरेत || 5 ||
>
> tasmātsarva-prayatnena prabodhayitumīśvarīm |
>  brahma-dvāra-mukhe
>   suptāṃ mudrābhyāsaṃ samācharet || 5 ||
>
> In order, therefore, to awaken this goddess, who is sleeping at the
>   entrance of Brahma Dwāra (the great door), mudrās should be practised
>   well.

---

## Why is Kundalini   resting ?

The answer is provided in the book  - [**Kundalini, The Mother of the Universe**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/kmu/kmu06.htm), by Rishi Singh Gherwal

As describe by author Kundalini as divine static energy  is sleeping at Muladhara Chakra and Dynamic enery of Kundalini flows all over the body.

> P.22  T**he Kundalini is Divine static and dynamic energy. The static
>   energy (Kundalini), is sleeping at the Muladhara (Root Chakra); the
>   dynamic energy of the Kundalini is all over the body as Prana, Apana,
>   Samana, Vyana, and Udana.** These five Vital breaths, or life forces,
>   keep the body together. The duties of the five Pranas are as follows:
>   Prana remains in the upper part of the body, and always moves upward;
>   the Apana resides in the lower part of the body, or abdomen, and
>   always flows downward; the Samana stays in the first section of the
>   torso, digesting and distributing the food substances; the Vyana
>   resides in the heart, and from there moves all over the body, its duty
>   being the circulation of the blood; the Udana carries the Soul upward
>   when the body dies.

Comment: Another important reference would be "Dnyaneshwari" by Shri. Sant Dnyaneshwar Maharaj wherein it is mentioned that "नागिणीची पिलें कुंकुमे नाहालीं". Means serpent with red colour.

Comment: @Vineet - Yes , correct Sant  Dnyaneshwar Maharaj was a great Yogi  and is talking about Kundalini in his various works. I did not specifically added that in answer because not many people are much aware of him since he belongs to specific region and his work is primarily in Marathi. Anyway nice to know that you are also aware about all his work . :-)